# Create a bat file to exit FFMPEG (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file, process, ffmpeg

Hello everyone I am using this bat file in order to capture my screen.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video=screen-capture-recorder -r 240001001 -q 1 lma_recording.avi
```

When I press the q button the video capture stops.

However I would like to stop the screen capturing with another bat file.

I have tried this:

`taskkill /im ffmpeg.exe`

without luck

Any suggestions?

Comment: The description for the `ffmpeg` tag says: Questions about using the ffmpeg command line tool should be asked on Super User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is screen capture recorder? is it an alternate executable's output? (im not familiar with ffmpeg) also, try this:

```
taskkill /im ffmpeg.exe /t /f
```

/f forces kill, and /t kills child processes too.

Comment: For me this results in a corrupt file that doesn't play.

Answer (score 5):

You can stop the recording sending the Ctrl-c signal to ffmpeg.exe with the SendSignal utility command, available at : https://github.com/AutoSQA/SendSignal

Once downloaded and selected your version (x86, x64) you can use it in this way:

```
sendsignal ffmpeg.exe
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: This is great. And it gracefully exits ffmpeg!

Answer (score 2):

```
taskkill /im ffmpeg.exe /t /f
```

The answer by [nephi12](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2525533/nephi12) works, but depending on the codec/container used for capture.

Capture to .avi works fine with this.
I usually capture h264 video to .mkv container, kill it with this command, then re-encode it to whatever I need.

On the other hand, for example capturing h264 video to .mp4 won't work, I believe because the kill command won't let ffmpeg write moov atom after capture end, and the file becomes unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Give your command window a unique title by adding this line before the call to FFmpeg:

```
title My Window Title
```

Then you can terminate it cleanly with taskkill.exe:

```
taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq My Window Title"
```